# "Invalid Contact ID" displayed after merge?

Tags: contacts, issues, duplicate-contacts

Drupal 7, Civicrm 4.7.4

I'm getting this error message after every contact merge. Any ideas?

---

### debug message

```
CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "Invalid Contact Id"

 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Dedupe/Merger.php(1945): civicrm_api3("activity", "create", (Array:5))
 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Dedupe/Merger.php(1834): CRM_Dedupe_Merger::createMergeActivities("55836", "197792")
 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Merge.php(318): CRM_Dedupe_Merger::moveAllBelongings("55836", "197792", (Array:35))
 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(423): CRM_Contact_Form_Merge->postProcess()
 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(160): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(61): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Merge), "next", "Next")
 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Merge), "next")
 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Merge), "next")
 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")
 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(113): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(286): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Contact_Form_Merge", "Merge Contact", NULL)
 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(454): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("contact", "merge")
 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
 {main}
 Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
Invalid Contact Id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah - if the contact id doesn't exist perhaps delete to trash is off?

Comment: We have a winner. Setting "Contact Trash and Undelete" in Administer > Misc (Undelete, PDFs, Limits, Logging, Captcha, etc.) fixes this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening as a result of [CRM-18106](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18106), "Add activity to deleted contacts showing they were deleted by merge".  I added a comment to that issue referencing this question.  In short: In Civi 4.7.4, this activity is added to contacts deleted by merge - part of a larger effort to make deduping reversible.  It's not working for you.  That's unfortunate - but the good news is that what's broken didn't exist before 4.7.4, so you shouldn't be experiencing any ill effects other than the error.

Answer (score 1):

This is now logged with a patch here https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18307

However if you are experiencing this I suggest you give serious consideration to enabling 'Contact Trash and Undelete' per Cullen McGough Mar 25 at 20:39 - since that setting is the default and for most sites having the delete to trash option turned on is a sensible precaution

Answer (score -1):

shot in the dark... any external ID's?